# Are the Møller wave operators $\Omega_\pm$ related to $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}U(t)$ from field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering

When we want to compute correlation functions $\langle\Omega|\,T\hat{\phi}(x_1)\ldots|\Omega\rangle$ in an interacting quantum field theory, we relate it to the free-field objects $|0\rangle$ and $\hat\phi_I(x)$ using the interaction-picture time-evolution operator in the limit $T\rightarrow\infty$.

Eventually, we arrive at an expression like (see Peskin and Schroeder eqn. 4.30)
$$\langle\Omega|\,T\hat{\phi}(x)\hat{\phi}(y)|\Omega\rangle=\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\mathcal{N}\langle 0|U(T,t_x)\phi_I(x)U(t_x,t_y)\phi_I(y)U(t_y,-T)|0\rangle.$$

The $U(T,t_x)$ and $U(t_y,-T)$ sitting at the end of the correlator look very much like the Møller wave operators of non-relativistic scattering theory

$$\Omega_\pm=\lim_{t\rightarrow\mp\infty}U(t)_\text{full}U_0(t),$$
that relate the in-asymptote and out-asymptote states to the actual state at $t=0$.

So my question is, are these two like the same thing, with the same properties?  *i.e.* they are isometric, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-relativistic expression for the wave operators

$$
Ω_±=\lim_{{t→∓∞}}U(t)_\text{full}U{_{0}}(t),
$$

needs revision in field-theoretic situations since usually the free and interacting fields act in different Hilbert spaces. An early example is given in

> "Asymptotic conditions and infrared divergences in quantum electrodynamics",  P. P. Kulish and L. D. Faddeev. [*Theoretical and Mathematical Physics* 1970, Volume 4, Issue 2, pp 745-757.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01066485).

Thus I expect that there is no simple answer to this question.

Comment: Very helpful response!  So, am I correct in saying that the the two operators are analogs, but the relativistic one requires revision?

Comment: From a mathematical point of view there are two things that must be proven for a given situation. The first is (obviously) the existence of the wave operators and the second is completeness, which is needed for the unitarity of the associated S-operator. The second is a rather non-trivial matter. In a field-theoretical situation it is already difficult to obtain a correct mathematical setting (divergencies, renormalisation) to start from.