# The validity of the Gell-Mann and Low theorem for non-normalizable state $\phi_{0}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, vacuum, ground-state

If we have a system with hamiltonian $H = H_{0} + H_{I}$, the [Gell-Mann and Low theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_and_Low_theorem) allow us to relate the exact state $\Psi$ of the interacting system with the ground state $\phi_{0}$ of the system without the interaction $H_{I}$. Here, $\phi_{0}$ is a eigenstate of $H_{0}$. However, This theorem is applicable only for normalizable states. But what happen if the $H_{0}$ hamiltonian has a continuum spectra and $\phi_{0}$ is not normalized? Is the theorem appliable yet?

Comment: It is certainly applied very widely for such states.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/272854/2451